# Best softwares for heavy pan/zoom editing?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, video-editor, editing, vegas-pro

I use to do a lot of pan/zoom editing with Sony Vegas Pro.
Now that I read that Sony plans to discontinue Vegas (they said it will remain supported but there will never be a new version again), I am checking other softwares, so far I have tested those but I would like to hear recommandations.
(I am also making heavy use of "Velocity envelope" in Vegas, I have not tested it in other softwares yet but I'm interested in feedback about similar or alternative features through different softwares. Maybe I should make it a different question.)

- **Sony Vegas**: Maybe it's because I used it for more than 10 years now but I think its pan/zoom tool is extremely flexible, and you can
  set transition speed/acceleration on keyframes.
- **Adobe Premiere Pro**: In their pan/zoom tools, it is possible (and seems to happen quite a lot if you do a lot of pan) to lose the corner
  outside of the interface. I don't find it intuitive at all. Maybe
  Premiere users are used to edit numbers rather than to manipulate the
  visual tool?
- **Adobe After Effects**: Looks like the best alternative so far as the tool's corners remain visible even when they are "behind" the
  interace. Though it is very close to that of Premiere, I found this one more intuitive. From a tutorial I watched this software's tool actually looks more precise than that of Vegas, but quite more complex to manipulate and obtain similar results.
- **Corel VideoStudio X8**: I am quite lost here and the interface gives me the feeling of a toy.

(Note: I use Windows so **Final Cut** is not an option.)

Comment: There's nothing firmly stated by Sony about the future of Vegas. The Catalyst suite still hasn't found its niche yet, and if all you're doing is Pan/Zoom then Vegas will keep on working regardless of future releases.

Comment: Thank you. I saw so many posts about that on Sony's forum that I though it was definitive. By the way I do other things than Pan/Zoom and Velocity envelope, but for some of my videos they're the most important parts of editing.

Comment: Update: Vegas Pro software has been acquired by [Magix](http://www.magix.com/gb/press/detail/?tx_news_pi1[news]=610) and they will release a new version in the Autumn.

Answer (score 1):

Go with After Effects, it's a tool that will most likely stick around. If necessary you can also take advantage of the more advanced tracking an compositing features. 
If you end up editing in Premiere (which pretty much is the best option if you don't want to dive into Avid) the integration between AE and Pr is crazy useful. I find myself even making titles there because it's just a faster and lets me do prettier stuff.
Let me know if you have any questions.